# How to test the touch screen on embedded devices like iPhone / iPad / Kindle?

Tags: linux, bash, embedded, touchpad, touch-screen

I want to test the touch panels on embedded devices like iPhone, iPad and Kindle against following criteria:

1. Do a gesture, like tap, swipe, pinch ( zoom in/out) 10000 times and validate that every time the gesture was indeed detected and was detected as a tap, swipe, pinch ( zoom in/out).
2. Do a tap on the touch panel (screen) 10000 times and make sure that the coordinate of the touched location as reported by the software stack is indeed where you did the tap.

Also I would like to get more ideas on what other touch testing can I do?

Comment: Sounds like you need to pick up some servos...

Comment: Do you know of any good servos/robotic tools out there?

Comment: If you were only intending to test the hardware in a VM, we could help, but I fear hardware is beyond our purview.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[Jason Huggins](https://us.pycon.org/2012/speaker/profile/392/)  gave a [fantastic talk](https://us.pycon.org/2012/schedule/presentation/471/) at [PyCon 2012](https://us.pycon.org/2012/) that described, in great detail, a robot that could play "Angry Birds" on the phone:

[image: robot playing angrybirds on iphone]

Worth [watching the talk](http://pyvideo.org/video/737/37-building-a-robot-that-can-play-angry-birds-on), it was very entertaining. 
Most importantly, the plans for the hardware and software of the core toolkit, [BitBeam](http://bitbeam.org/pages/about), are online in a [github repo](https://github.com/hugs/bitbeam). I'm sure it would give you a great start.

Comment: Can you please send me a link to the "hardware and software plans online." ? Much appreciated!

Comment: Updated links to bitbeam and associated github repo.

Comment: This is rather awesome. :)